# What do you call the different types of characters of a password when it is being validated?

Tags: security, passwords, cryptography, terminology

I hope this question is not too pedantic, but is there a technical term for the different "categories" that are part of a password when it is being validated? [For example](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftechnet.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fcc786468(v%3Dws.10).aspx&ei=VstPVKOALrDgsAT3toKgDQ&usg=AFQjCNGMqgtvbjsJlrhxDFmSOr-pP9kPNQ&sig2=rZ8Z2Q2rmGgVNo6ULbMlhA&bvm=bv.77880786,d.cWc) default AD password complexity requirements that must be met (Microsoft calls them "**categories**"):

```
Passwords must contain characters from three of the following five **categories**: 

Uppercase characters of European languages (A through Z, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters)

Lowercase characters of European languages (a through z, sharp-s, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters)

Base 10 digits (0 through 9)

Nonalphanumeric characters: ~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|\(){}[]:;"'<>,.?/

Any Unicode character that is categorized as an alphabetic character but is not uppercase or lowercase. This includes Unicode characters from Asian languages.
```

Is there a term used by security engineers or cryptographers to refer these "categories"?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, I don't think there is a generic term. However, one term is character sets/pools and actually a more correct way to refer to these is "password complexity rules".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not any *official* term for these. I would tend to call it a "character type".

For example, this term is used in Novell's document [Creating Password Policies](http://www.novell.com/documentation//password_management33/pwm_administration/data/an4bun5.html?view=print):

> The password must contain at least one character from three of the four types of character, uppercase, lowercase, numeric, and special

and this [NIST document regarding Enterprise Password Management](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/drafts/800-118/draft-sp800-118.pdf):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, in 10 years working in security, no final and shared nomenclature has been given for this. MS "Categories" is a good one and probably the most used, but it is not formally shared among each context (i.e. Java could call it differently, PHP, OWASP, Oracle, ..., could have their own)

Academically speaking, they are only factors to enlarge the basic character set of an offline bruteforce attack, rainbow table creation time or avoid trivial dictionary brute. Bruteforce complexity is roughly 2|C|^n where n is the expected length of the password and C is the character set chosen, and |C| is the number of elements in there.

Having more categories increases the value of |C| - so they should be called something like "password character set subsets" instead of "categories" but you see why nobody bothers with the theoretical bit here, nomenclature is unfriendly.

If you look for it and you find the way academics call them, please post it, it is always useful.